# Error during matplotlib pip installation

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, pip

My attempts to install `matplotlib` with `pip` fail with the following error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 2 in /tmp/pip-build-P9kEsn/matplotlib/

I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#build-requirements

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, pip install is supposed to resolve the dependencies right.??

Comment: Only python package dependencies, not build dependencies

Comment: @xi_ : worked after upgrading all dependencies. Thank you.!

Comment: @JesseBakker : Thank you for the clarification.